# Compiling the linux kernel source and not sure if this correct behaviour?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora

I'm compiling the linux source code on a different machine to where I will be testing this (I'm trying to see if I can trace if/where a commit that is causing some weird behaviour on my machine), and I therefore want to try to build packages which I can install on the test machine.

The test machine runs Fedora, so, therefore, I would use `make binpkg-rpm` to generate those packages.

The output I get is two rpms -- one for the kernel and one for the headers. All good.

Some things I noticed at this point, however:

1. The kernel rpm is HUGE -- like 1G+ in size.
2. The kernel-headers package obsoletes `kernel-headers` (and the rpm generation actually warns of this). Removing this package after installation makes Fedora want to remove a TON of other packages.
3. There are no separate module packages (e.g. `kernel-modules`, `kernel-modules-extra`)

So a few questions I have regarding the compilation process (and I cannot find any documentation on the web to answer these)

1. Why is the generated kernel rpm so big?
2. Why are there no separate modules rpms? Is there a switch I need to use to generate these?
3. Why does the kernel-headers generation throw that obsoletes message and why does removing it make Fedora want to remove so many other packages?

I did use the kernel config of the current running kernel (i.e. I copied the config from the `/boot` folder and renamed it .config)

Many thanks in advance for any guidance, even if it's just pointing me to a page which answers my questions (that my hours of searching didn't uncover)

Comment: **1.** The kernel you have has all debuginfo inside them, i.o.w. the binaries are not stripped. **2.** The RPM script inside Linux kernel is for generic RPM, it doesn't mean any distribution in mind. To compile for Fedora you need to take Fedora RPM and update the spec accordingly with providing additional patches on top of it. **3.** See **2.** above.

Comment: Here you go: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel.

Comment: Thanks, @0andriy I did see that page during my search, but that page only describes compiling and installing to the local machine, and not building the rpms (it refers to `make modules_install` and `make install`). Remember I am building on a different machine to where I intend to install it. Secondly, the page referring to building from a source RPM (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel/Source_RPM) implies installing a src RPM. In theory, would I able to use the vanilla source here instead?

Comment: If I had been you, I would have taken the _*.src.rpm_ of Fedora kernel (closest to your needs), and update with additional patches you need. That's how RPM is supposed to be built for any software (not only user space or kernel).  If you really need vanilla, it maybe much easier to have it compiled and installed manually. Like you create a custom folder locally where you install kernel, modules, and simply `tar` + USB stick OR `ssh` it to another host (of course the CPU architecture should be compatible).